# Submitting a word count topology to my storm cluster, created jar using Eclipse but it is showing Exception

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, apache-storm

I am trying to submit a word count topology to my storm cluster. I created a jar using Eclipse but it is showing exception.

Can anybody tell me what to do. I am attaching my code and exception here.

**Spout Creation-**

```
public class WordReader implements IRichSpout {
    private SpoutOutputCollector collecter;
    private BufferedReader bufferedreader;
    private FileReader filereader;
    private Boolean completed=false;
    private TopologyContext context;
    private final static Logger logger=LoggerFactory.getLogger(WordReader.class);
    @Override
    public void ack(Object msgId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Ok"+msgId);
    }
    @Override
    public void activate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        logger.info("Activating Storm");        
    }
    @Override
    public void fail(Object msgId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Fail"+msgId);   
    }
    @Override
    public void nextTuple() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(completed)
        {
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e)
            {
                System.out.println("String is Interrupted");
            }
        }
        String line;
        bufferedreader=new BufferedReader(filereader);
        try {
            while((line=bufferedreader.readLine())!= null)
            {
                this.collecter.emit(new Values(line));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            completed=true;
        }   
    }
    @Override
    public void open(Map map, TopologyContext context, SpoutOutputCollector collector) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        this.context=context;
        try {
            this.filereader=new FileReader(map.get("InputFile").toString());
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            throw new RuntimeException("Error reading file");
        }
            this.collecter=collector;}
    @Override
    public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        declarer.declare(new Fields("line"));
    }
}
```

**Bolt code-**

```
public class WordNormalizer implements IRichBolt{
    private OutputCollector collecter;
    @Override
    public void cleanup() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
    @Override
    public void execute(Tuple input) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String sentence=input.getStringByField("line");
        String[] words=sentence.split(" ");
        for(String word:words)
        {
            word=word.trim();
            if(!word.isEmpty())
            {
                word=word.toLowerCase();
                ArrayList a=new ArrayList();
                a.add(input);
                this.collecter.emit(a,new Values(word));
            }
            collecter.ack(input);
        }   
    }
    @Override
    public void prepare(Map conf, TopologyContext context, OutputCollector collector) {
            this.collecter=collecter;
    }
    @Override
    public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
        declarer.declare(new Fields("word"));
    }
}
```

**Bolt Counting Frequency-**

```
public class WordCountBolt implements IRichBolt {
    private OutputCollector collector;
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private Map<String, Integer> counter;
    @Override
    public void cleanup() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : counter.entrySet())
        {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey()+" "+entry.getValue());
        }

    }
    @Override
    public void execute(Tuple input) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String str=input.getStringByField("word");
        if(!counter.containsKey(str))
        {
            counter.put(str, 1);
        }
        else
        {
            Integer i=counter.get(str)+1;
            counter.put(str, i);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void prepare(Map conf, TopologyContext context, OutputCollector collector) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        this.counter=new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        this.collector=collector;
        this.name=context.getThisComponentId();
        this.id=context.getThisTaskId();
    }
    @Override
    public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {}
}
```

**Main Class Creating Topology-**

```
public class StormMain {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //Configuration
        Config conf = new Config();
        conf.put("InputFile",args[0]);
        conf.setDebug(false);
        TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();
        builder.setSpout("word-reader",new WordReader());
        builder.setBolt("word-normalizer", new WordNormalizer()).shuffleGrouping("word-reader");
        builder.setBolt("word-counter", new WordCountBolt()).shuffleGrouping("word-normalizer");
        //Topology run
        conf.put(Config.TOPOLOGY_MAX_SPOUT_PENDING,1);
        LocalCluster cluster = new LocalCluster();
        cluster.submitTopology("TopologyMain",conf,builder.createTopology());
        //Thread.sleep(1000);
        //cluster.killTopology("TopologyMain");
        cluster.shutdown();
    }
}
```

**Edit Exception**

This is the Exception which I'm getting:

```
     org.apache.storm.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn - caught end of stream exception
org.apache.storm.zookeeper.server.ServerCnxn$EndOfStreamException: Unable to read additional data from client sessionid 0x14cb812ae720003, likely client has closed socket
    at org.apache.storm.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn.doIO(NIOServerCnxn.java:228) ~[storm-core-0.9.3.jar:0.9.3]
    at org.apache.storm.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory.run(NIOServerCnxnFactory.java:208) [storm-core-0.9.3.jar:0.9.3]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_71]
6056 [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2000] INFO  org.apache.storm.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn - Closed socket connection for client /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:55127 which had sessionid 0x14cb812ae720003
6057 [ProcessThread(sid:0 cport:-1):] INFO  org.apache.storm.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor - Processed session termination for sessionid: 0x14cb812ae720005
6076 [main] INFO  org.apache.storm.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Session: 0x14cb812ae720005 closed
6076 [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2000] INFO  org.apache.storm.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn - Closed socket connection for client /127.0.0.1:55133 which had sessionid 0x14cb812ae720005
6076 [main-EventThread] INFO  org.apache.storm.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - EventThread shut down
6076 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.supervisor - Shutting down supervisor 3b4d74c2-9fa3-4b8d-beb8-419063c95c02
6077 [Thread-3] INFO  backtype.storm.event - Event manager interrupted
6077 [Thread-4] INFO  backtype.storm.event - Event manager interrupted
6078 [ProcessThread(sid:0 cport:-1):] INFO  org.apache.storm.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor - Processed session termination for sessionid: 0x14cb812ae720007
6097 [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2000] INFO  org.apache.storm.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn - Closed socket connection for client /127.0.0.1:55139 which had sessionid 0x14cb812ae720007
6097 [main] INFO  org.apache.storm.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Session: 0x14cb812ae720007 closed
6097 [main-EventThread] INFO  org.apache.storm.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - EventThread shut down
6098 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.supervisor - Shutting down supervisor e94ee8a8-f38f-4ba4-a48f-4427a7c8d30d
6098 [Thread-5] INFO  backtype.storm.event - Event manager interrupted
6098 [Thread-6] INFO  backtype.storm.event - Event manager interrupted
6099 [ProcessThread(sid:0 cport:-1):] INFO  org.apache.storm.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor - Processed session termination for sessionid: 0x14cb812ae720009
6117 [main] INFO  org.apache.storm.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Session: 0x14cb812ae720009 closed
6117 [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2000] INFO  org.apache.storm.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn - Closed socket connection for client /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:55145 which had sessionid 0x14cb812ae720009
6118 [main-EventThread] INFO  org.apache.storm.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - EventThread shut down
6118 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.testing - Shutting down in process zookeeper
6118 [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2000] INFO  org.apache.storm.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory - NIOServerCnxn factory exited run method
6119 [main] INFO  org.apache.storm.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer - shutting down
6119 [main] INFO  org.apache.storm.zookeeper.server.SessionTrackerImpl - Shutting down
6119 [main] INFO  org.apache.storm.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor - Shutting down
6119 [main] INFO  org.apache.storm.zookeeper.server.SyncRequestProcessor - Shutting down
6119 [ProcessThread(sid:0 cport:-1):] INFO  org.apache.storm.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor - PrepRequestProcessor exited loop!
6119 [SyncThread:0] INFO  org.apache.storm.zookeeper.server.SyncRequestProcessor - SyncRequestProcessor exited!
6119 [main] INFO  org.apache.storm.zookeeper.server.FinalRequestProcessor - shutdown of request processor complete
6120 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.testing - Done shutting down in process zookeeper
6120 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.testing - Deleting temporary path C:\Users\Rishi\AppData\Local\Temp\8335008e-119b-4ae3-a557-2839d573a579
6128 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.testing - Deleting temporary path C:\Users\Rishi\AppData\Local\Temp\8c53a710-6448-441e-bf01-734b80f9b989
6130 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.testing - Unable to delete file: C:\Users\Rishi\AppData\Local\Temp\8c53a710-6448-441e-bf01-734b80f9b989\version-2\log.1
6130 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.testing - Deleting temporary path C:\Users\Rishi\AppData\Local\Temp\1ea20791-599d-483d-9ffd-37445005684c
6136 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.testing - Deleting temporary path C:\Users\Rishi\AppData\Local\Temp\ef85048c-77e3-4392-8fc1-41bb4547ab53
8027 [SessionTracker] INFO  org.apache.storm.zookeeper.server.SessionTrackerImpl - SessionTrackerImpl exited loop!
```

Comment: It seems the connection to Storm or Zookeeper server is closed. Please verify that.

Comment: I have checked the connection of storm and zookeeper as well they are up and running

Comment: could you please try removing the `cluster.shutdown();` part

Comment: solved using collector.ack(input) in WordCountBolt class in the execute function but their is one problem as we have to call cleanup function manually in the main for displaying the output.....so what can we do for making cleanup function to be called automatically????

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Instead of using LocalCluster we have to use StormSubmitter for submitting the topology.....I used it and it works, now I have my topology on the Storm UI

```
cluster.submitTopology("TopologyMain",conf,builder.createTopology());
```

Replace it with--

```
StormSubmitter.submitTopology("TopologyMain",conf,builder.createTopology());
```

Answer (score 2):

Had a pretty similar issue where on running the program it got stuck at :

```
[SessionTracker] INFO  org.apache.storm.zookeeper.server.SessionTrackerImpl - SessionTrackerImpl exited loop!
```

Resolved it by removing

```
cluster.shutdown();
```

as it was not allowing zookeeper to communicate with storm.

Answer (score 1):

Just increase the length of time that the thread sleeps 
e.g.

```
Thread.sleep(10000);
```

Make it 10000 and then check.
It is because your Map task is taking much time.